# Does anyone know how I can get rid of hex A0 from a string?

Tags: php, javascript, hex

I have the following string:

> Hello.    Hello.

If you look at the string in a hex editor it looks like this:

> 48 65 6C 6C 6F 2E 20 A0 20 20 48 65 6C 6C 6F 2E

Note the `A0` in the middle. (This is the no-break space character).

`A0` is breaking some JavaScript I am using so I would like to remove it when the string is being pre-processed by a PHP script.

If I use the following code:

```
$text = preg_replace("/\xA0/"," ", $text);
```

the `A0` gets replaced with `00` which is also a troublesome character.
As you can see from the `preg_replace` function, it should be replace by a space, or `20`.

Do any of you know how I can get rid of this troublesome `A0` character?

Thank you.

EDIT: I am using Windows-1252 and cannot switch to UTF-8. This won't be a problem if you are using UTF-8...

Comment: The bigger question to me is: why does it break your JavaScript? That's worrisome. What other characters that you don't know about are breaking your script? Do you want to play whack-a-mole until you've found them all?

Comment: @deceze: You bring up a good point. Honestly, I do not know why it is a problem. It seems JSON doesn't like it. In the bit of research I've done it seems A0 is considered a security risk, so perhaps it is disallowed. But I am not sure... thankfully I figured out a solution (see below).

Comment: I found this useful. Closing it as too localised serves no purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution:

First convert the encoding type, and then do the replace:

```
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
$text = preg_replace("/\xA0/"," ", $text);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple

```
$string = str_replace(chr(160), " ", $string);
```

Simple Test

```
$string = "48656C6C6F2E20A0202048656C6C6F2E" ;
                        ^----------------------- 0A

//Rebuild String
$string = pack("H*",$string);

//Replace 0A Charater 
$string = str_replace(chr(160), " ", $string);

//Send Output 
var_dump($string,bin2hex($string));
```

Output

```
string 'Hello.    Hello.' (length=16)
string '48656c6c6f2e2020202048656c6c6f2e' (length=32) 
                     ^---------------------- 0A Replaced with 02
```

Comment: Doesn't work, sorry, but thank you for trying. The character still gets replaced by 00.

Comment: Tested this with both [UTF DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rZrMCG) and [Windows-1252 Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jGnRCB) .... ..if your hex is `A0` then it would definitely be replaced

Comment: Honestly, it replaces A0 with 00. Have a look at the string it produces: Hello. �   Hello. My hex is definitely A0. See my solution below, it seems a two step process is necessary. Very strange!

Comment: @Steve you should take a look at it carefully .. it produce `� ` because i wanted to show you [UTF demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rZrMCG) showing before and after ... It would be better for you to look at the var_dump carefully again

Comment: Baba all I can tell you is if you use the string I provided with your solution in PHP 5.4, it does not solve the problem. It causes the exact same issue I described in my question. It's OK to be wrong, no worries... the problem is now solved. EDIT: Actually the string on this page has the A0 removed hence why it is probably working for you! My original string with the A0 does not like your solution... if you use the hex codes I provided to create the string you will be able to test your solution properly.

Comment: @Steve am not using a string ... am using the hex you provided `48656C6C6F2E20A0202048656C6C6F2E` if that not the case then you are misleading anyone that should answer the question .... since you can tell the difference when `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and asking me why  �  then its not worth replying you.

Comment: Relax baba, no need to get angry. It seems to be an encoding issue. I was using Windows-1252, you were using UTF-8. Try it in Windows-1252 and you will see the issue. Note I definitely should have mentioned I am using Windows-1252 in the question. My apologies. (Note I am restricted to using Windows-1252).

Comment: I should be angry  i gave you 2 demos .. one uses `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and the other `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1252');` ... You could not even take your time to look at simple 10  then you come back and say `Actually the string on this page has the A0 removed` ... thanks for wasting my time ...

Comment: Baba, you have just drastically edited your solution. Your original solution DOES NOT WORK with my code. Accept it does not work with my code and move on with your life, get some fresh air, relax. It's OK. :)